# .net 3.5 application on .net 4.0 runtime

Tags: .net

If I have an application built to target .net 3.5, will it run if all the user has installed is .net 4.0? A link to official msdn documentation stating this would put my worries to rest.

Comment: On something like this, keep in mind that even a link to official MSDN documentation is no substitute for actual testing. Theoretical compatibility does not necessarily equate with real-world results.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Plus one for all of you. Great answers. I love stack overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is most probably, and here are the MSDN tools to determine if your app will have issues.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Specifically "By default, an application runs on the version of the .NET Framework that it was built for. If that version is not present and the application configuration file does not define supported versions, a .NET Framework initialization error may occur. In this case, the attempt to run the application will fail." Everyone helped but I can only mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it can. You can say that you support .NET 4 in your `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" /> 
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Note that changes in the framework may break your app. For details, see MSDN's list of [.NET 4 migration issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee941656(v=vs.100).aspx), which includes recommended changes.

If you still want to support users with only .NET 3.5 installed, you also need to add a `<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />` element:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" /> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> 
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Note that the above configuration prefers .NET 4.0 if that is installed. Changing the order above makes the application prefer .NET 3.5 if that is installed. A complete table of possible configurations and effects can be found in MSDN's how-to on [configuring your app to support .NET 4.0 or 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks man. This is what I need to do. But everyone gave great answers. You were second by a second I guess :) +1. Much appreciated.

Comment: What if only 3.5 is installed? I believe you should also add `<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>` (before `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />` if you want it to take precedence when both are installed). For example see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11211795/67824

Comment: Yes, as per @OhadSchneider 's comment, you must add the `<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />` element if you want the app to run on computers with only 3.5 installed. See [the table in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx) on configuring an app to support .NET 4.0 or 4.5 for a complete overview of possible settings and effects.

Comment: @HåvardS probably best if you edited your answer, I doubt many people want their 3.5-compiled program *not* to work when run in a system where only 3.5 is installed...

Comment: btw you can add a manifest to existing programs (if they don't include it in resources already). For example, there is winzpaq.exe, which tries to run on .NET 3.5 by default. Adding winzpaq.exe.config with above contents allows running it on 4.0 and above :)

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx)

This is important:"The .NET Framework 4 is highly compatible with applications that are built with earlier .NET Framework versions, except for some changes that were made to improve security, standards compliance, correctness, reliability, and performance."

Comment: From your link exactly what I needed "The .NET Framework 4 does not automatically use its version of the common language runtime to run applications that are built with earlier versions of the .NET Framework. To run older applications with .NET Framework 4, you must compile your application with the target .NET Framework version specified in the properties for your project in Visual Studio, or you can specify the supported runtime with the <supportedRuntime> Element in an application configuration file.
" but there can be only one excepted answer. +1 nonetheless.